# Assign value to a variable string in bash

Tags: bash, shell

```
ITEM_DATE="2019-10-23"
ITEM_VARIABLE="product_date='$ITEM_DATE'"
RESULT_VARIABLE=`eval echo $ITEM_VARIABLE`
```

ITEM_VARIABLE is being generated dynamically from reading a file, hence the need to eval.
I want RESULT_VARIABLE="product_date='2019-10-23'"  [single quote required]
but I am getting RESULT_VARIABLE="product_date=2019-10-23"  [single quotes missing]

Comment: eval will evalaute value of ITEM_DATE and assign it to the string producte_date='2019-10-23'

Comment: No `eval` is required for that. `ITEM_VARIABLE` already contains exactly that.

Comment: @tripleee aah sorry that string vaule for ITEM_VARIABLE , I am getting from a file so ITEM_VARIABLE is being generated dynamically hence the need to eval.

Comment: The code you have in your question doesn't do that, and we can only comment on the code we can actually see.

Comment: @tripleee my mistake, just consider that ITEM_VARIABLE hold dynamic value, taken from a file. really appreciate you help..

Comment: Hey. Would it be possible with sample file and output you need. You might need to use typeset command to generate variable dynamically.

Comment: "ITEM_VARIABLE is being generated dynamically from reading a file". That's the first mistake. `bash` is not a templating language; don't try to force it to be one.

Comment: @chepner well situation demads it to be, I managed to assign value to a dynamic string variable the only issue is that eval is removing quotes while I need quotes.

Comment: Without a reproducible example it's hard to see what more to say here. Maybe look at variable indirection. You really want to avoid `eval`, especially in combination with an apparently incomplete understanding of the shell's quoting facilities.

Comment: @tripleee it's entirely reproducible, create a file with olny content [product_date='$ITEM_DATE'] , read this file and assign content to a variable ITEM_VARIABLE. Rest of the question remains same.

Comment: For reproducibility here, set `ITEM_VARIABLE="product_date='\$ITEM_DATE'"` to simulate the value you would get from a file containing the literal text `product_date='$ITEM_DATE'`.

Comment: It is "reproducible" when the question itself contains exactly what you need to reproduce the problem and answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some quotes.

```
RESULT_VARIABLE=$(eval "echo \"$ITEM_VARIABLE\"")
```

The parameter expansion produces (roughly) `echo product_date='$ITEM_DATE'`; then the `eval` causes `ITEM_DATE` to be expanded.

```
$ ITEM_VARIABLE="product_date='\$ITEM_DATE'"
$ ITEM_DATE="2019-10-23"
$ RESULT_VARIABLE=$(eval "echo \"$ITEM_VARIABLE\"")
$ echo "$RESULT_VARIABLE"
product_date='2019-10-23'
```

## WARNING

This requires you to know *exactly* what the values of `ITEM_VARIABLE` and `ITEM_DATE` and what string could be produced as the argument to `eval`, though. I really don't recommend this approach. Use a proper templating language to generate your data instead of using pure shell.

Comment: single quotes are still missing with your approach. Out put should be product_date='2019-10-23'

Comment: I used the wrong type of quotes to wrap `$ITEM_VARIABLE`; you need double quotes so that the single quotes in `ITEM_VARIABLE` remain escaped. Note the fragility this implies: you also need to adapt to the contents of `ITEM_VARIABLE` to avoid executing unintended code.

Comment: you are awesome